# Passing values from various textboxes to another

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have few different radio buttons and four textboxes. What I want to achieve is to get values from all textboxes and display it all in one summary textbox (summary). I have managed to get values from all radio button however I cannot get the values from textboxes.

I want this to look like this:  RB1 - RB2 -RB3 - TXTB1 - TXTB2 - TXTB3 - TXTB4

Please see code below that retrieves text from all radio buttons:

I have added the provided code but it does not seem to be working well:

```
 private void summary_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                var radios = this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().OrderBy(x => x.TabIndex)
                   .SelectMany(x => x.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
                   .Where(x => x.Checked == true)
                   .Select(x => x.Text).ToList();

            this.summary.Text = string.Join("-", radios);

                var textboxes = this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().OrderBy(x => x.TabIndex)
                    .SelectMany(x => x.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
                    .Select(x => x.Text).ToList();

             this.summary.Text = string.Join("-", textboxes);

        }
```

Comment: So why is this not adaptable to `TextBox`?

Answer (score 3):

Well if you have got this far, the answer is pretty simple:

```
private string GetTextFromTextBoxes()
{
    var textboxes = 
             this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>()
                          .OrderBy(x => x.TabIndex)
                          .SelectMany(x => x.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
                          .Select(x => x.Text);

    return string.Join("-", textboxes);
}
```

That is offcourse assuming the textbox are also in the groupboxes. If the textboxes are directly on the from you'll remove the call to SelectMany and change the first `OfType<GroupBox>` to `OfType<TextBox>`

**UPDATE**

> Keeps freezing up while starting...

If you call this code in the TextChanged event of the `Summary TextBox` you have created an endless loop. Because when the `TextChanged` event is called when, how could it be different, the `Text` property of the `TextBox` is changed. But because you set this text inside that event, the event will be raised again and again and so on.

So you have to figure out when the summary textbox needs to updated and call the code from that point or event in your code. That's the reason I created a function which composes the text instead of directly changing the text in the textbox in the code above.

Comment: I believe that changing the ending to `.Select(x => x.Text).ToList();` will also return the string.Join in the format that's he looking for as well.

Comment: Thank you, I have added the code to my app but something goes wrong and app keeps freezing up while starting. I am not sure if I add it at correct place.

Comment: private void summary_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
var radios = this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().OrderBy(x => x.TabIndex)
.SelectMany(x => x.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
                   .Where(x => x.Checked == true)
                   .Select(x => x.Text).ToList();
this.summary.Text = string.Join("-", radios);

var textboxes = this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().OrderBy(x => x.TabIndex)
                    .SelectMany(x => x.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
                    .Select(x => x.Text);

            return string.Join("-", textboxes);
        }